# Is emulator like console?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-emulator, console

Does a console for java basically serve the same purpose an emulator does for android. Would whatever shows up in the console show up in the actual application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console only shows text. the emulator runs your app as if your app is running on an android smart phone. You get to use your application almost exactly how it would be used on a phone, only much slower.

for debugging you'd use Log.d() to print to the emulator log instead of system.out.print

Answer (score 1):

No, a console is just character-based IO. An emulator is something that pretend it's a completely different environment.

And no, Android doesn't expose a console by default, most interaction takes place through GUI components.

Comment: So if I was making an actual java application I would have to use log.d() instead of System.out.println to get output in the application?

Comment: @user1371576 Define "output": log statements will go to the log file; not the screen.